# C++ pointers, How to?

Tags: c++, winapi

I need to pass a pointer to an `std::string` as the `LPARAM` of a `WM_USER` message and get the string or `char*` in the `WM_USER` message handler of the main window.

How do I do that ?

What I am doing now (which is incorrect, since its not producing the result it should):

```
PostMessage(hwnd, LP_DOWNLOADUPDATE, (WPARAM)hHandleToWindow, (LPARAM)&remSize);
```

Where `remSize` is a `sdt::string remSize;` a global variable.

And in the message handler I am doing :

```
SetWindowText( (HWND)wParam, (char*)lParam );
```

Comment: Use `std::string::data` or `std::string::c_str`. Don't randomly cast it to a `char*`. If it's global, why are you bothering to pass it?

Comment: You must make sure that the string is still allocated in memory until the call to ON_MESSAGE is finished. If not you will have big problems!

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Just must get a C-style string, i.e. a pointer to a zero-terminated array of characters:

```
PostMessage( hwnd, LP_DOWNLOADUPDATE, (WPARAM)hHandleToWindow, remSize.c_str() );
```

Make sure `remSize` doesn't go out of scope until you can be sure that the message has been processed, or else there will be dangling pointer.

Comment: I thought &remSize mean pointer to the first byte of the character string :P Untill I realize that string in c++ is a class :?

Answer (score 1):

You're sending the address of a `std::string`, and you're interpreting it as a `char*`. This can't work. You need to interpret the pointer as it was sent - as the address of a `std::string`:

```
SetWindowText( (HWND)wParam, ((std::string*)lParam)->c_str() );
```

Answer (score 1):

Instead of `(LPARAM)&remSize` you need to pass `(LPARAM) remSize.c_str()` to convert your `std::string` to a const `char*` (i.e. to extract the pointer from the `std::string` instance).

Answer (score 1):

When you use `PostMessage` the call returns immediately, and the message is just placed in the receiving thread's message queue. If the referred to object then goes out of scope, the receiving code will be referring to a non-existent object. Which is Undefined Behavior.

Instead, use `SendMessage` to pass the data. The receiver can then copy the data and use `PostMessage` (if so desired) to remind itself to process the data later.

Anyway, if you start with a pointer to `std::string`, then the receiver can't cast it to `char const*` or some other unrelated type. Either pass a pointer to `std::string` and interpret as a pointer to `std::string` at the receiving end. Or pass a pointer to `char const*` and interpret it as pointer to `char const*` at the receiving end.

---

Summing up:

- Pass pointed-to data via `SendMessage`, not via `PostMessage`.
- If so desired, use `PostMessage` to invoke later processing of something.
- Don't cast pointers between unrelated types.

Comment: In the app I am downloading files and from the event that occurs during the download I call postmessage according to some conditions, I use postmessage instead of sendmessage so as to not interrupt the download process. What you say ? I am using curl for the download.

Comment: `SendMessage` doesn't interrupt the receiving thread. It waits for that thread (if it is a different thread) to call message queue functions, then synchronizes. The problem for the sender is that this wait can be long if the receiver doesn't ever even inspect the message queue. So, make sure it does that. And then keep in mind that i/o is *extremely* slow compared to internal processing such as storing away a string value. ;-)